# Pipe on init not working on reactive form Angular 14

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-pipe

I am trying to create an input component with reactive form that only accepts number. I want the output to be with decimals. I added the pipeline on the value property and also created a directive to transform values that already have decimals back to numbers. The problem i have is that on init of the component, the control has a starting value, the output is shown without decimals. When i enter any number the decimals will appear correctly.

The template

`<input inputWithComma`
`[value]="control.value | number"`
`[formControl]="control">`

The component

```
  @Input() control: FormControl = new FormControl();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
```

The directive

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[inputWithComma]',
  providers: [DecimalPipe]
})
export class NumberCommaDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  private subscription: Subscription = new Subscription;

  constructor(private ngControl: NgControl, private decimal: DecimalPipe) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const control = this.ngControl.control;

    this.subscription = control!.valueChanges.pipe(
      map(value => {
        if (isNaN(Number(value))) {
          value = value.replace(/[A-Za-z!@#$%^&*(),]/g, '');
        }

        return parseInt(value);
      })
    ).subscribe(v => {
      if (v) {
        control!.setValue(v, { emitEvent: false })
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.subscription) {
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
}
```